# Working with shared folders and printers in AD with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

Is there a way to manipulate permissions for using shared folders and/or printers for Active Directory Users and Groups using PowerShell ?
I've been reading about Get/Remove/Set-QADPermission but i can't seem to find an example for shared folders or printers. 
Edit

Lets say I have a group witch has access to a couple of shared folders and printers. When i create another group, how can i get the access to the same folders/printers from the previous group?

Empo answered how to get access to folders (thanks again), can somebody please help me with getting access to a shared printer as well?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? Do you want to manipulate rights on AD objects (which publish in AD shared directories and shared printers), or rights on Shared objects themselves. On one hand you configure who can see the shared objects thru AD. On the other you configure acces to the shares.

Comment: I really don't know. I want a user (or a group) to get access to a shared folder or a printer, by using powershell cmdlets. What path i'll take to achieve this is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the cmdlets `Get-ACL` and `Set-ACL`. The former returns the security descriptor of the selected provider in terms of `System.Security.AccessControl`. You can use the returned object to manipulate permissions and then reset the security descriptor back using the latter cmdlet.

For examples of using the cmdlet you can see:

```
get-help Get-ACL -examples
```

You might be interested also in reading this [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/11/09/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell.aspx).

Comment: Thanks empo. Your answer was helpful, but only for a part of my question (for which i am guilty of not knowing how to define it). Lets say we have a group witch has access to a couple of shared folders and printers. When i create another group, how can i get the access to the same folders/printers from the previous group?

Comment: May be you prefer going with [Subinacle](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Yea, thats the easy way out.But I would like to know if i can do it with powershell.